# How to catch timeout exception with IPC::Run on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, perl

I am trying to catch a timeout exception with [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) on Windows 10 (using Strawberry Perl version 5.30.1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;
use IPC::Run qw(run timeout);

my $timeout = 3;
my $cmd = ['perl', '-E', "sleep 5; say 'stdout_text'; say STDERR 'stderr_text'"];
my $in;
my $out;
my $err;
my $result;
eval {
    $result = run $cmd, \$in, \$out, \$err, timeout($timeout );
};
if ( $@ ) {
    say "Timed out: $@";
}
else {
    print Dumper({  out => $out, err => $err});
}
```

The above program dies after 3 seconds with:

```
Terminating on signal SIGBREAK(21)
```

How can I catch the timeout exception in the Perl script?

See also [this](https://github.com/toddr/IPC-Run/issues/98) issue.

Comment: Did you try to handle the signal?  Perhaps like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771631/4653379)

Comment: @zdim Thanks for link, yes it seems to work with a `$SIG{BREAK}` handler installed!

Comment: Just got around to try it -- and I don't get a SIGBREAK, but an actual exception (handled by `eval` as usual). This is on Windows 10 (in a VM) with Strawberry Perl v5.30.2; the `IPC::Run` source shows `$VERSION` of `20200505.0`. (I'm confused?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @zdim! You need to install a signal handler for the `BREAK` signal. The following works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;
use IPC::Run qw(run timeout);

my $timeout = 3;
my $cmd = ['perl', '-E', "sleep 4; say 'stdout_text'; say STDERR 'stderr_text'"];
my $in;
my $out;
my $err;
my $result;
{
    local $SIG{BREAK} = sub { die "Got timeout signal" };
    eval {
        $result = run $cmd, \$in, \$out, \$err, timeout($timeout );
    };
}
if ( $@ ) {
    say "Timed out: $@";
}
else {
    print Dumper({  out => $out, err => $err});
}
```

**Output**:

```
> perl p.pl
Timed out: Got timeout signal at p.pl line 14.
```