# AsyncTimeout in Async.pm giving timedout only after completing the execution of async process

Tags: perl, asynchronous

I am using [AsyncTimeout](https://metacpan.org/pod/Async#AsyncTimeout) perl package to invoke a process asynchronously with timeout in seconds. The process is taking more time to complete, it is returning "Timed out" msg only after completing the process.

Is there a way to stop the process and return timed-out?

Comment: Is this on Windows? You could also try [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run)

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of your code? See [mcve] for more information..

Comment: Yes, it is on windows.

Comment: Sample Code:

my $timeout = "10";
my $retval = AsyncTimeout->new(sub {fun1()}, $timeout, "Timed out");
while (defined $retval) {
    my $e;
   if ($retval->ready()) {
}
}

Comment: Can you try the example in [How to catch timeout exception with IPC::Run on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65894287/2173773) ?

Comment: As I am trying with Asynchronous timed out, IPC will not work. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Yes, I can see from the documentation that it has no support for running sub routines asynchronously on Windows.. If that is what you mean?

Comment: So, because of subroutine, it is not working. If it can be directly with the block, it will work. Is it correct?

Comment: Is that a long running computation? The timeout in AsyncTimeout is implemented using `alarm()` which is not automatically delivered on windows. If you can call `sleep(1)` from time to time (in your worker callback) you loose a second but the alarm will get caught.

Comment: Yes, it is a long running computation. Can you ellaborate on which place you are suggesting to add sleep

Answer (score 1):

The timeout in AsyncTimeout is implemented using alarm() which is not automatically delivered on windows. If you can call `sleep()` from time to time (in your worker callback) the alarm will get caught.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Async;

my $proc = AsyncTimeout->new(sub{for (1..10000){
                                          print "count: $_\n";
                                          sleep(0);
                                          }
                                 },
                              1,
                              "my timeout\n");

while (defined $proc) {
  print "Main program:  The time is now ", scalar(localtime), "\n";
  my $e;
  if ($proc->ready) {
    if ($e = $proc->error) {
      print "Something went wrong.  The error was: $e\n";
    } else {
      print "The result of the computation is: ", $proc->result, "\n";
    }
    undef $proc;
  }
  # The result is not ready; we can go off and do something else here.
  sleep 1; # One thing we could do is to take nap.
}
print "main process continues\n";
```

prints

```
count: ...
count: 5555
The result of the computation is: my timeout

main program continues
```

This works with strawberry 5.22 and 5.32. If you have to do long running system calls this approach will be of no use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, with the above approach, it would come out with time out, but still $proc is undefined, as the async process is running in background or stopped